# How to only show explicitly created Tasks (not Calendar events) in Outlook's To-Do bar?

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, productivity, tasks, gtd

What I essentially want is a sidebar or panel which only displays Tasks I have explicitly created. I don't want all the Calendar events in there as it's just noise to me, I'd look at the Calendar if I wanted those.

I can see how to apply filters but criteria available to differentiate between Tasks and Calendar events.

[image: Outlook 2013 tasks screenshot]

In the above example, there should only be two entries in the To-do pane. "Set up signatures in Outlook" and "Pay storage fees". I don't want to see any of the others which aren't really tasks.

I'm aware there are add-ins such as Todoist which can help with this but I'm not interested in yet another service which I have to sign in to, nor trying to integrate the same task lists with other clients besides Outlook. If there is a free add-in which just works with the native Outlook / PST tasks I'd possibly accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple =) Just right-click To-Do pane header, select **View Settings**, click **Filter** button and go to the **Advanced** tab. On this tab click the *Field* drop-down and select **All Task fields** -> **In Folder**. Set **contains** as a **Condition** and type *Tasks* to the **Value** text box. Click **Add to List** button and click **OK**, then again **OK**. That's all!

Comment: Legend! This works perfectly.